# I am using Hawtio(2.7.1) stanalone jar and trying to add new plugin in it. But it showing an error

Tags: hawtio

I am using **HawtIO (2.7.1) standalone jar** and trying to add new custom plugin in it but its throwing an exception as 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlKtt.png)**"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to delete temp dir C:\Users\e5601428.hawtio\tmp                                        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configureTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:376)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.resolveTempDirectory(WebInfConfiguration.java:264)                      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:69)                               at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)                                          at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)                                               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)                               at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)                             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)                                   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)                               at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)                             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)                                                             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at io.hawt.embedded.Main.run(Main.java:154)                             "**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgZIB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom plugin is not yet supported in 2.7.1. It will be supported in 2.8.0 (we will release it soon). For the time being you can test it by checking out the source repository and run `mvn clean install` to get `hawtio-app/target/hawtio-app-2.8-SNAPHOST.jar`.

You can test a custom plugin by running as follows:

```
java -jar hawtio-app/target/hawtio-app-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar -pd examples/simple-plugin/target/
```

after building the full project.

Comment: But it is scanning my plugins folder and wars files present in that that folder.

Comment: Yes, hawtio-app.jar scans `./plugins` folder by default unless you designate `-pd` option as shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to design plugin in angular 2 or more?

Comment: No, Hawtio 2 still sticks to AngularJS 1.x and there is no plan to move to Angular 2+. In the future we would rather migrate to React.

Comment: Thank you. I have taken latest HawtIO(2.0.X) build from git, but I didn't see sample plugin after running it on browser. What should I do?

Comment: 2.0.x isn't the latest branch. The latest one is master. You can use 2.8.0 as it's already released by the way.

Comment: I made latest master build. Now it is showing `Hello world` message from controller on browser, but when I try to fire `localhost:100000/hawtio`, (using server port)it shows me error as "Whitelabel Error Page". When I try to use management port it shows `{"timestamp":"2019-11-08T07:17:55.966+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found","path":"/hawtio"}` (I am using **hawtio-master\examples\springboot**) .

Comment: Read README first: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/hawtio-2.8.0/examples/springboot/README.md  The URL of Hawtio console is: http://localhost:10001/actuator/hawtio/index.html

Comment: Is it possible to integrate **spring security** with **hawtio 2.8.0** while adding angularjs plugins?

Comment: Is it possible to manage user roles in hawtio 2.8.0? User management is added in hawtio 2.8.0 or not?